# Connect two servers with OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, centos5, linux-networking

guys,

I need a consulting.
I need to connect two servers which are located at another places geographically. One of servers is at LeaseWeb, and another is at our office in Moscow.

I'm using OpenVPN for tunneling. I installed OpenVPN via `yum -y install openvpn`. After this I'm trying to up interfaces.

On first server:

```
/usr/sbin/openvpn --remote 217.28.227.46 --dev tun1 --ifconfig 172.16.1.1 172.16.1.2 
Wed Jul 31 18:07:31 2013 OpenVPN 2.2.2 i686-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] built on Apr  5 2012
Wed Jul 31 18:07:31 2013 IMPORTANT: OpenVPN's default port number is now 1194, based on an official port number assignment by IANA.  OpenVPN 2.0-beta16 and earlier used 5000 as the default port.
Wed Jul 31 18:07:31 2013 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Wed Jul 31 18:07:31 2013 ******* WARNING *******: all encryption and authentication features disabled -- all data will be tunnelled as cleartext
Wed Jul 31 18:07:31 2013 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Wed Jul 31 18:07:31 2013 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Wed Jul 31 18:07:31 2013 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 172.16.1.1 peer 172.16.1.2
Wed Jul 31 18:07:31 2013 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]:1194
Wed Jul 31 18:07:31 2013 UDPv4 link remote: 217.28.227.46:1194
Wed Jul 31 18:07:41 2013 write UDPv4 []: No such process (code=3)
Wed Jul 31 18:07:51 2013 write UDPv4 []: No such process (code=3)
Wed Jul 31 18:08:02 2013 write UDPv4 []: No such process (code=3)
Wed Jul 31 18:08:12 2013 write UDPv4 []: No such process (code=3)
```

Command on a second server is the same:

```
/usr/sbin/openvpn --remote 95.211.186.49 --dev tun1 --ifconfig 172.16.1.2 172.16.1.1
Wed Jul 31 18:08:41 2013 OpenVPN 2.2.2 i686-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] built on Apr  5 2012
Wed Jul 31 18:08:41 2013 IMPORTANT: OpenVPN's default port number is now 1194, based on an official port number assignment by IANA.  OpenVPN 2.0-beta16 and earlier used 5000 as the default port.
Wed Jul 31 18:08:41 2013 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Wed Jul 31 18:08:41 2013 ******* WARNING *******: all encryption and authentication features disabled -- all data will be tunnelled as cleartext
Wed Jul 31 18:08:41 2013 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Wed Jul 31 18:08:41 2013 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Wed Jul 31 18:08:41 2013 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 172.16.1.2 peer 172.16.1.1
Wed Jul 31 18:08:41 2013 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]:1194
Wed Jul 31 18:08:41 2013 UDPv4 link remote: 95.211.186.49:1194
Wed Jul 31 18:08:51 2013 write UDPv4 []: No such process (code=3)
Wed Jul 31 18:09:01 2013 write UDPv4 []: No such process (code=3)
Wed Jul 31 18:09:11 2013 write UDPv4 []: No such process (code=3)
Wed Jul 31 18:09:21 2013 write UDPv4 []: No such process (code=3)
```

Interfaces are upped and seems to work. Unfortunately, I can't to ping, for example, IP 172.16.1.2 from first server. I mind with these messages about UDP. Can you suggest - does my hoster blocks UDP? I wrote a message them, and they told they're blocks tcp/445 and tcp/139 only (it's LeaseWeb).

What I've omitted, in general?

Both my servers are CentOS 5.9 x86. LeaseWeb's server is a Xen DomU, second node are in KVM hypervisor in our office.

Thanks.

Comment: try to add --verb 5 to the command line and try again

Comment: OK, with this option: http://pastebin.com/sSenXFrS Am I right it's a network problem? Someblockings or etc.

Comment: It seems so, first of all run tcpdump on both of sides and check which ones is blocks connection. After that you could try to switch to tcp protocol and try again

Comment: Thanks, problem was solved. The reason was in IPsec configured previously by me. I haven't reboot, so have errors during communications between the servers.